# How to launch an HTML file in an external web browser via a shortcut in the toolbar

Tags: eclipse, html, browser

Sorry, if this question is already ansewered! I have configured my external browser and I can launch any html file via right clicking this file and choosing open with.... What I would like to do is launching any file via a shortcut in the toolbar by just clicking on this shortcut and right click on file --> open with.... So if there is any possibility to get this shortcut, please tell me how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i guess you refer to eclipse:

had the same problem, it's really annoying that there is no default behaviour of eclipse to deal with html files.

here is how i did it with pictures! ;)

http://dwaves.de/index.php/2014/01/16/eclipse-run-launch-html-htm-webpage-in-external-browser-external-tools-shortcut-hotkey/

eclipse as web editor – do it yourself – howto:
eclipse is per default configured to be used for java development.
but if you want to “run” a html site in your external browser… nada. You have to configure it yourself, like this:
1. download eclipse
2. start eclipse (this was tested with Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: Kepler Service Release 1 Build id: 20130919-0819)
3. install the plugin “web page editor” help -> new software -> select All Sites -> search for “web page editor” -> check the checkbox -> click next, next, agree, restart.
this is what you will get (when you r-click on a document and choose “open with” -> “web page editor”, reminds me of dreamweaver’s preview.

now in order to “launch” / start the website with a shortcut:
1. setup firefox as default browser: “window” -> preferences -> search for browser -> choose “external browser” and search for the firefox.exe

1. define external tool command

you should get a new command in your run-suitcase-symbol.

when you click it… firefox should launch your website.
in order to shortcut-this go again into preferences, search for “keys”
and asign a key-combination to the “Run Last Launched External Tool”

that’s the best way right now i know of.
Feel free to comment!